JPanel not showing up in JFrame - again
I know that this question has been posed a plenty of times and I'm feeling to have skimmed really a lot of threads, tutorials and whatsoever about it in the last 3 hours, but I'm stuck, I simply do not understand what is wrong, as it looks so simple, but simply doesn't work...
I've got a GUI based program (working fine), with the gui built up in a view-class extending JFrame, building up the gui, and so on, all standard. There is JButton in the view-class generating an instance of another class (called GReader in the snippet below), the constructor of which calls a method of this class and within this method, another method in the same class is called. The structure of the GReader class reads as follows:
public class GReader {
 JFrame frame;
 JPanel panel;
 JProgressBar bar;

public GReader (>> constructor input <<) {

  someMethod(input);

}

  
  someMethod(>> method input <<) {

     createProgressBar(some number);

     loop { here: update of bar.setValue(progress indicator) }

     closeProgressBar();
  
  }


  private void createProgressBar (int maxValue) {
        frame = new JFrame("Operation Progress");
        panel = new JPanel();
        bar = new JProgressBar(0, maxValue);
        bar.setValue(0);                        // initial value
        panel.add(bar);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        // bar.setVisible(true);
        // panel.setVisible(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

  private void closeProgressBar() {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();
    }
}

As can be seen, the purpose of this construction is simply to monitor the progress of some operation. All functionalities in the GReader class work as expected, except the display of the operation progress.
I've also read about ProgressMonitor and tinkered around a bit with it, but without result. The snippet above now shows the very first attempt, as any modification ended up in one and the same observation: panel does not show up in frame. Just the JFrame appears - empty and after packing reduced to a window of 3 by 2 cm. The rest (not shown in the above code/pseudo-code mix) works fine, the operation completes (without progress monitor...) and so on.
Why does the JFrame stay empty? Is it not possible to simply open 2 windows in parallel with content? Is this a general misconception on my side? Or does this require more complex measures, like starting a new thread, or so?
Thank you very much for any hint.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the How to Use Progress Bars section.  The task has to be a Swing Timer or a SwingWorker.

So, it's a general misconception. Thanx, that's the answer I needed.

Btw. I've read the Use Progress Bars section, however, not to the very details. A SwingWorker does not make sense, as it is not a long-running task but a large sequence of short tasks. I just wanted to have a quick graphical display of the loop counter, would have been nice. The rest is all too cumbersome - my time is limited for playing around with my tools, work's focus is different... I'll put out the loop counter on the terminal. Nevertheless, again thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question.

I've included a working example.  Not certain why you want to establish the frame and panel when you create the ProgressBar.

is someMethod(>> method input <<) being called on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), blocking the EDT and so the GUI? If not, the createProgressBar  is NOT being called on the EDT, as requested by Swing's Threading Policy

You're missing quite a few details.  Here is one solution but your will have to retrofit it to you design. It is best to subclass JPanel so you can override getPreferredSize().  You may need to add a ChangeListener to track progress events.  It depends on your design.
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GReader extends JPanel {
    JFrame frame;
    JProgressBar bar;
    int value;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new GReader());
    }

    public GReader() {
        frame = new JFrame("Operation Progress");
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center on screen
        frame.setVisible(true);
        createProgressBar(50);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    private void createProgressBar(int maxValue) {
       
         bar = new JProgressBar(0, maxValue);
        bar.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        bar.setForeground(Color.GREEN.darker().darker());
        bar.setStringPainted(true); // show percentage
        
        Timer t = new Timer(1000, a-> {
             value++;
             bar.setValue(value);
           
             if (value > maxValue) { //reset for demo
                 value = 0;
             }
        });
        t.setDelay(250);
        t.start();
        bar.setValue(0); // initial value
        add(bar);
    }

   
}


@rebit  I added a working progress bar for the demo.  This will have to be retrofitted into your design.
